# Way too easy but still fun, plus it rhymes, fun in a bun!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

I like the grass, I like the dew,
I make a sound that sounds like you,

I'm the horned god of the east,
Though not one that upsets a priest,

It's not too rare if I am blue,
Otherwise too tough to chew,

A mighty thundering meat beast,
I'd rather not be at the feast...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you refering to

> a cow?

I like the grass, I like the dew, I make a sound that sounds like you,

> Mooh! .. and obviously cows like grass

I'm the horned god of the east, Though not one that upsets a priest,

> I guess there are lots of cows in the east? Dont knot about this one tho..
>  **Thanks to ROAL / Inazuma for reminding me of the religious aspect of the cow in India**
>  Also thanks to the OP for hinting towards the [Horned God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horned_God)

It's not too rare if I am blue, Otherwise too tough to chew,

> refering to Cordon Bleu maybe?
>  **Thanks to Inazuma for the hint!
>
>  A 'blue' steak is basically a raw steak, much less cooked than rare.**

A mighty thundering meat beast, I'd rather not be at the feast...

> Not sure about this one too

Feel free to edit / suggest something if you know more than me ;)

Comment: I'm guessing: It's not too rare if I am blue -

A 'blue' steak is basically a raw steak, much less cooked than rare.

Comment: Also 'I'm the horned god of the east' = Hindus worship cows, and I'm guessing though they don't upset priests in Christianity

Comment: "I'm the horned god of the east" - cows (and bulls) are considered sacred in some cultures.

Comment: The last line might just be that a cow doesn't want to be eaten (haha)

Comment: Thats true @ROAL .. I guess I could've come up with that too since a co-worker of me is Indian  - Thank you too Inazuma!

Comment: Try googling "The horned god" if you want to flesh it out a bit.

Comment: That gave me a laugh @BrentHackers :D Would edit my post a little more about that but my english is way to bad to explain it all in a short sentence so I'm just gonna link the wiki page if thats fine with you ;)

Comment: @radhato I don't mind.  Go nuts.  You got everything pretty much covered anyway.

Comment: Holy Cow!! this was an easy riddle.

Comment: @Marius owch... I feel like I was just run over by a giant wheel of cheesiness.  You're right though , it was an easy one.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> the moon?

I like the grass, I like the dew, I make a sound that sounds like you,

> Moon sounds a little like "moo", which is a child's term for a cow.

I'm the horned god of the east, Though not one that upsets a priest,

> A crescent moon has horns, and rises in the east. The moon was formerly worshipped as a god.

It's not too rare if I am blue, Otherwise too tough to chew,

> An event that happens once in a blue moon is a rare event. Moon rock is too tough to chew.

A mighty thundering meat beast, I'd rather not be at the feast...

> I don't know about this.

Comment: Cool, but the answer was far simpler...

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Deer or a stag?
>
>   Deer graze on grass in the early hours when dew is on the ground
>
>   Horned God in the east may refer to the Nepali legend of Pashupati, basically Shiva hiding out in deer form away from the missus. 
>
>    I must confess I have no way to tie a deer to the color blue, nor tough to chew (venison jerky doesn't seem like a likely tie-in)
>
>   Deer or venison meat is eaten by many.

Comment: Sorry.  Some good ties but this wasn't the answer I was looking for.